# How pass own data to $.Event object?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

is possible pass own data to $.Event object in jQuery?

This works

```
 e = {
        type: "phnx",
        namespace: "anychange",
        __myOwnValue: 123
      }

      return $element.trigger(e);
```

And what in this case?

```
e = $.Event("phnx.anychange");
e.data = 123; // not working
e.data = {__myOwnValue : 123} // not working
```

is possible to do that somehow?

Comment: If you look at the https://api.jquery.com/trigger documentation, you can pass data as a secondary argument, after the event type

Comment: Its not working of course ... I tried ...

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: e = $.Event("phnx.anychange", {
  'key': someValue
});

Comment: No dude, the extra options go on the `trigger()` call, not on the event itself.  Read the documentation

Comment: ```

e = $.Event("phnx.anychange");
      // e = {
      //   type: "phnx",
      //   namespace: "anychange",
      //   __myOwnValue: 123
      // }

      return this.$element.trigger(e, {
        __myOwnValue: '123' 
      });
```

Still not works :(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MmumCgqR

Comment: http://files.rjwebdesign.cz/f/20200129-170513.mp4 (short video with debug)

Comment: OK, im home :) http://files.rjwebdesign.cz/i2/20200129-170807.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9e5zg80c/  You don't put the namespace on the event you are generating.  The namespace should go just on the binding.

Comment: Thx, but that is not exactly what i wanted in this topic. 
See my example: you will see 2 different approaches but own data are stored directly in EVENT. 

https://jsbin.com/bucoromake/1/edit?html,js,output

And now Im looking (purely of my own interest) for way how to do that but in syntax with $.event (i want own data directly in event object).

It is understandable?

Comment: I want to get my own data from  e.data.mydata or e.mydata with $.event object.
How to get into in?

Comment: Im done -> https://jsbin.com/memoriyate/edit?html,js,console,output